# Why does my SharedPreferences do not update everytime I change its value?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am making an encryptor app.
The problem is that I converted *action_settings* button in a sharing one.
So the thing that I want is:
Everytime someone writes in the EditText (for example: Hello) and clicks Encrypt button, that string stores in SharedPreferences and its ready to share in WhatsApp, Telegram.. (thats made with shareactionprovider).
But in my case, it doesnt matter if you encrypt 2 words one after the other.
It only stores the first one.

How can I change it so it can share the last word that has been written?

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button borrar, encriptar, desencriptar;
EditText palabra;
String  cambio;
TextWatcher tt = null;
int i;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    encriptar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnencriptar);
    desencriptar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndesencriptar);
    palabra = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);


    encriptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //button that encrypts
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String texto = palabra.getText().toString(); //string taken from edittext






            texto = texto.replace("a", "9R"); //changes "a" with "9R", the same with the rest of the alphabet is below
            texto = texto.replace("b", "9G");
            texto = texto.replace("c", "9B");

            texto = texto.replace("d", "8R");
            texto = texto.replace("e", "8G");
            texto = texto.replace("f", "8B");

            texto = texto.replace("g", "7R");
            texto = texto.replace("h", "7G");
            texto = texto.replace("i", "7B");

            texto = texto.replace("j", "6R");
            texto = texto.replace("k", "6G");
            texto = texto.replace("l", "6B");

            texto = texto.replace("m", "5R");
            texto = texto.replace("n", "5G");
            texto = texto.replace("ñ", "5B");

            texto = texto.replace("o", "4R");
            texto = texto.replace("p", "4G");
            texto = texto.replace("q", "4B");

            texto = texto.replace("r", "3R");
            texto = texto.replace("s", "3G");
            texto = texto.replace("t", "3B");

            texto = texto.replace("u", "2R");
            texto = texto.replace("v", "2G");
            texto = texto.replace("w", "2B");

            texto = texto.replace("x", "1R");
            texto = texto.replace("y", "1G");
            texto = texto.replace("z", "1B");




            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

            editor.putString("Name", texto);

            editor.apply();

            palabra.setText(texto);


        }
    });
}





        public void desencriptar(View v) { //this converts 9R to a, 9G to b...

            String texto2 = palabra.getText().toString();
            texto2 = texto2.replace("9R", "a");
            texto2= texto2.replace("9G", "b");
            texto2 = texto2.replace("9B", "c");





            palabra.setText(texto2);

        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { // here is the share button that shares the stored value


            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);
            ShareActionProvider
                    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
            // Create the share Intent
            Intent shareintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareintent.setType("text/plain");

            SharedPreferencespreferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);//the problem maybe is here where I load the string value
            String name = preferences.getString("Name", "");

            shareintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, name);

            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareintent);


            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.menu_share) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Here it is the **xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/edittext1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ENCRIPTAR"
    android:id="@+id/btnencriptar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edittext1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DESENCRIPTAR"
    android:id="@+id/btndesencriptar"
    android:onClick="desencriptar"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnencriptar"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edittext1"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/edittext1" />
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just have to ask: Why don't you use proper encryption?

Comment: Try moving shared preference initialisation code from button click and make it global

Comment: And is there a reason you are using `SharedPreferences` in your code? I don't get what you are trying to accomplish. You don't need it.

Comment: I think I need it to pass the string to share it. Am I wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to store multiple values on the same key? Because that does not work.

Comment: I am trying to store only one. Every time you write in the edittext, it is stored. The thing that I want is to store the last word that has been written so if you click in shrabutton, it shares the last one. Right now it is only sharing the first word you write the first time you use the app.

Comment: @SR.David Because you are only storing the current value in the listener of `encriptar` and not shrabutton...

Comment: Thanks @MuratK.How can I store it in sharebutton. (Sorry... I am new..)

Comment: @SR.David Well, where is your sharebutton. Can't see it in your code.

Comment: It is this: public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

Comment: @SR.David Ok, nonetheless you have to call `editor.putString("Name", "some new string");` wherever you want to store a new string.

Comment: I want to store the string that I get from users input in edittext

Comment: editor.putString("Name", texto); "texto" is the string that I get from user input which is the one that I want to store

Comment: I dont want to store a string that I write by myself, I want to store the user input